# ActiveMQ with Apache Karaf 2.3.1

Tags: java, osgi, activemq-classic, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I have ActiveMQ 5.8.0 and Karaf 2.3.1 running separately.

What I did in Karaf was: (have all other: spring, cxf, camel already installed)

- `features:addUrl mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/5.8.0/xml/features`
- `osgi:install -s mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-camel/5.8.0`

`features:list | grep mq` shows:

```
[uninstalled] [2.11.0         ] camel-amqp                              camel-2.11.0
[uninstalled] [2.11.0         ] camel-mqtt                              camel-2.11.0
[uninstalled] [5.8.0          ] activemq-client                         activemq-5.8.0
[uninstalled] [3.1.3.RELEASE  ] spring                                  activemq-5.8.0
[uninstalled] [5.8.0          ] activemq-broker                         activemq-5.8.0
[uninstalled] [5.8.0          ] activemq-http                           activemq-5.8.0
[uninstalled] [5.8.0          ] activemq-camel                          activemq-5.8.0
[uninstalled] [5.8.0          ] activemq-web-console                    activemq-5.8.0
```

If I install `activemq-broker` it will install the server and everything of ActiveMQ, I don't need that.

In one of my bundle I am exposing camel-cxf endpoint, from which I am sending the message to the queue. The problem is that when I am trying to install my bundle it gives me an error:

```
missing requirement [169.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.activemq)
```

I know that some of the features installed in Karaf has to export this package: `org.apache.activemq`, but they does not.

I can't find any information what features to install in Karaf that it will be using activemq stuff separately. I don't want Karaf to have ActiveMQ running in it. I just need necessary features installed.

Can anyone please point me which features I need to install for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. I needed to install only `activemq-client`. This does not install all other features.

```
features:install activemq-client
```